# How can I store only the parts that are changed in the scraped data from a website that updates frequently?

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, database-design

**Some Background**

I'm developing a website that uses scraped data from another website (about 40 pages). This other website makes small changes in its data often. I have no way of knowing what changed. Majority of the data remains the same for a good amount of time. I have the web-scraper as a python script that runs as a cron job every hour, and updates the database I'm using for the website to be developed.

**The problem**

Currently, what I'm doing to update the database is truncating entire tables and repopulating them again with the new **scraped** data (the entire thing).

This is obviously an expensive operation because 40 pages produces a lot of data and majority of it the same, and that is why I want to avoid it.

**My question**

Is there a way I can update the database with only the changes and keep the unchanged data as is in the database? Again, I have no way of knowing what changed.

Answer (score 0):

am working on a similar problem, here is the solution I came up with:

1. setup a reverse proxy with caching on the *scraped* websites (here is a sample config with nginx : https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/)
2. In ur script, every 1 hour make two requests: one to your proxy cache (on localhost for example) and another to the original website.
3. if response is the same: no update to the db. if not : update your db the way you are doing now.

Note: you might have to tweek nginx config as some website do set header response with fields intended to stop caching (see : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_headers)

Comment: This is still expensive for me because I have to make requests to ~40 pages just to check if the content is updated or not. It's still the same problem.

Comment: am confused where is the bottle neck, fetching data or storing it?

Comment: I want to avoid fetching everything when majority of the data is the same.